# Playframework 1.2 redirect wtih content type

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to embed PDF file in PlayFramework application. So I get file path and do redirect

```
response.setHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
redirectToStatic("/data/attachments/"+file.file.getUUID());
```

but content-type not changing. Default value that setting is plain/text

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to set the content-type, Play! comes pre-bundled with lots of mime types already defined. Chances are that the "/data" directory is not defined in your routes configuration as containing static content.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

### create a pdf.html[not necessarily, you can also put this in an existing page]

```
<object data="test.pdf" type="application/x-pdf" TITLE="test.pdf">
    <a href="public/test.pdf">ClickToOpenPdf</a> 
</object>
```

### insert this to your routes

```
GET     /pdf                                    Application.pdf
```

and add test.pdf into your public folder. Because

```
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public
```

is already defined in routes, all files under public folder will be served succesfully(eg. *hostname:port/public/test.pdf* )